# Any way to export data frames and graphs to a pdf without latex?

Tags: r

I have several data frames and graphs that I want to place into a pdf file. I know of Sweave and knitr, but they both use latex to create a pdf file, and I don't want users of the code to need to download Latex before they can use it. Is there any way at all to send data frames into as a table (with a  title) and graphs as the same document? If not, is there any way to send the data frames into one document and the graphs into another? I'd be glad to see any reasonable way, as long as it's possible to make it all automated.

Comment: You could use markdown and process that to HTML and then print HTML to PDF with a browser. Not elegant, but does not use LaTeX.

Answer (score 6):

One basic example,

```
library(gridExtra); library(ggplot2)
ggsave("plotntable.pdf", arrangeGrob(qplot(mpg, cyl, data=mtcars), 
                                     tableGrob(mtcars[1:10, 1:4]), ncol=2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The plotrix package has the function `addtable2plot`, so you could open a pdf device and create your plots, then for the tables just create an empty plot (`plot.new` and `plot.window`) and use `addtable2plot` to put the data frame (if it is small enough) into the empty plot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for graphs.

```
pdf(file = "pdf_demo.pdf")
plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
dev.off()
```

See `?pdf` for details, and `ggsave` if you're using `ggplot2`.

I'm not so sure about tables. You may be able to use [`pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) and `Rmd`. Or just write the tables as `.csv`. Pandoc, at least, can be installed pretty easily using the `installr` package. **Edit** looks like Pandoc uses LaTeX to create PDF's.